# How to GCM server register id and what is mechanism to send message

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm following [this example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) for GCM is work fine just tell me the mechanism how server sent message to every register device how it will uniquely identify each device. what I `SENDER_ID` what is `regId` how server uniquely identify my device how php server sent message to each device without SMS email service tell me its mechanism please how it will work
in this application I have few this

```
String SENDER_ID = "748495904142"
```

which I receive from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1#project:748495904142:access

```
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

// Check if regid already presents
if (regId.equals("")) {
    // Registration is not present, register now with GCM           
    GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
} else {
    // Device is already registered on GCM
    if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
        // Skips registration.              
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Already registered with GCM",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
        // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
        // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
        final Context context = this;
        mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // Register on our server
                // On server creates a new user
                ServerUtilities.register(context, name, email, regId);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                mRegisterTask = null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: app is running perfectly i just want to know what is going backend what is SENDER_ID what is regId  how php server message to each device

Answer (score 1):

SENDER_ID is project id which Server uses to distinguish between different Projects associated with the server.

REG_ID is a unique id which Server uses to distinguish between different Mobile Devices registered with the server.

Now for example, Same Mobile Device is associated with two different projects and is associated with the same server hence providing an ease to the server to distinguish between the two projects and send respective message to the Mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

when you register your project on the APIs console you got a number for your project, that number is the SENDER_ID also u get an API key from the console. In android when executed

`final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);`

then the mobile check for the registration with gcm,if already registered with the gcm server then it will return a regId. these id is different for different mobiles. The  gcm server identify your mobile using this registration id. After getting the regid we save that to our database for future use. On server side we just send the message and registration id to the gcm server,the gcm server identify the phone by using the registration id and send the notification to the appropriate mobile.